# Weird issue regarding my hashing function

Tags: php, hash, bcrypt, blowfish

I am using the exact same function twice in two different `functions.php` areas.

1. Once in the installer - when the user is registering.
2. And twice in the main script, when user logs in.

#### Registration output

```
 username: admin
 password: 12345678
 hashed password: $2y$12$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$.ibwcWrMlgLR7y6B62/Vc8Dc54kecHHe$1$ZQhX9D2d$RexVJ.y2KWpfxMyY0tN9E1
 salt: HJsZ4yBWNbGQCw1Yi-7rGBunXym7AEIFatIHhaK_fQgY6I1ecqAEs7eAmJM88Zdn5VpdrKie2CN39~PjqSb3yoPCCzl4q8
 vsalt: S2qXSXQUc-
```

#### Login output (same input)

```
  username: admin
  password: 12345678
  hashed password: *0S2k0u9.1hnFr.
  salt: HJsZ4yBWNbGQCw1Yi-7rGBunXym7AEIFatIHhaK_fQgY6I1ecqAEs7eAmJM88Zdn5VpdrKie2CN39~PjqSb3yoPCCzl4q8
  vsalt: S2qXSXQUc-
```

#### Code for the hashing function

```
function hashing($password ,$salt ,$vsalt){
    $check1 = crypt($password.$salt,'$2y$12$'.$vsalt);
    $check2 = crypt($password.$salt,$vsalt);
    //password will be: $check1.$check2
    return($check1.$check2);
}
```

#### The Issue:

Hashed passwords don't appear exactly the same

Comment: Looks like two separate algorithms...perhaps it isn't using the same function like you think?  I say that because the installer registration output hash is Blowfish, while the login one isn't.

Comment: They are exactly the same yet I messed around with the functions and again copy pasted and now it seems work fine ...

Comment: nope still not working it saves now as a magical *0 for people that doesn't know what *0 or *1 means: it's blowfish failure

Comment: I have worked arround with my function and changed alot I will add the solution to this question. it works for me now

Comment: I don't think you need a separate salt when you use Bcrypt.

Comment: seperating the salt in this case has another function after all but that's not mainly what thise gone over about...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things jump out:

1. The salt used for Bcrypt has a limited "alphabet" of `[./A-Za-z0-9]`, so a hyphen should not be used.
2. The salt should be 22 characters long.

Lastly, IMHO, because you're using a salt with Bcrypt you don't really need another salt to pad the password.

The following function should work just fine:

```
function hashing($password, $salt, $cost = 12)
{
    assert(preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9.\/]{22}$/', $salt);
    return crypt($password, '$2y$' . str_pad($cost, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . '$' . $salt);
}
```

That said, you should be using the [password hashing API](http://php.net/password) which has been included into the core since 5.5. For older versions you can use [password compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) which implements the same interface.

Comment: also the 110 chars cur salt works also fine for some reason the only issue was the last $ (salt = 100 chars | vsalt = 10 chars)

Comment: @MikeM. The last `$` is not needed; in fact, I don't see that anywhere in the documentation and I certainly wouldn't call it a fix. The first 110 chars salt is irrelevant.

Comment: as the documantary shows the correct salting is $x$xx$xxxxxx$

Comment: @MikeM. *My* documentation states " Blowfish hashing with a salt as follows: "$2a$", "$2x$" or "$2y$", a two digit cost parameter, "$", and 22 characters from the alphabet "./0-9A-Za-z"." ... no mention of a trailing $.

Comment: I meant in the example it states: echo 'Blowfish:     ' . crypt('rasmuslerdorf', '$2a$07$usesomesillystringforsalt$') . "\n";

Comment: oh and yet after I added the trailing $ and it worked.

Comment: @MikeM. Perhaps it may work out that way, but a 22 char salt is still the recommended way of using Bcrypt; that, and sticking to the correct alphabet of letters, digits, period and slash.

Comment: @MikeM. The vsalt itself should be 22 chars; the salt you add to the password can theoretically be any length you wish.

Comment: salt + vsalt makes the salt for blowfish I didn't want to update the function again so just updated salt and vsalt size xD

Comment: `$blowFishSalt = '$2y$12$'.$vsalt.$salt.'$';
$check1 = crypt($password.$salt,$blowFishSalt);` is how the function looks like

Comment: @MikeM. IMHO you're needlessly complicating your password hashing, but regardless, my above two points still stand uncorrected :)

Comment: uhm I did move to a 22 char salt about the first point meh I don't really think it's a big difference to use a regex to create the 5:29 AM here right now and going to sleep :D my login and install registration now aswell so my guest for today is done ;)

Comment: @MikeM. Where did I use a regex to *create* the salt? The salt should be created outside (and should be random every time) and then passed in; the assertion just makes sure the salt is valid for use with Bcrypt.

Comment: my salt is random which is passed over with only a-z A-Z and 0-9 yet I made a mistake  with preg_match xD you just used it to make sure the salt key is 22 chars long and only accepts a-z A-Z 0-9 but the randomizer I am using only can pick out of a-z A-Z and 0-9 so it's totally not needed and the randomizer also only passes in total of 22 chars nothing more or less

Comment: @MikeM. You mentioned in the question that vsalt was "S2qXSXQUc-" which clearly has a hyphen *and* is too short; perhaps you're confusing your question with the answer you've posted? ;-)

Comment: the question yes the salt was to short but was also randomized. the hyphen was just a copy mistake, but still the answer of my doesn't include any hyphen (it actually never did) and the salt is intotal of 22chars min/max

Comment: @MikeM. - Take Jack's advise and do without the `crypt()` function, use instead the password API.

Answer (score -2):

**My solution:**

The function:

```
function hashing($password ,$salt ,$vsalt){
    $blowFishSalt = '$2y$12$'.$vsalt.$salt.'$';
    $check1 = crypt($password.$salt,$blowFishSalt);
    //password will be: $check1.$check2
    return($check1);
}
```

The main issue of returning the *0 (failure code can also be: *1):

```
 my blowfish salt: $2y$12$_RANDOM_STRING_ 
 Correct blowfish salt standards: $2y$12$_RANDOM_STRING_$
```

thanks for anyone that tried to help!

Have a nice day!

Comment: This is exactly the reason, why PHP has a new function [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), so that nobody should make such mistakes again! This is an absolute misuse of the `crypt()` function and it is luck if it works at all, not to mention that it is unsafe because of the incorrect salting.